# Photo/Video gallery running not smooth when sliding to the left or the right

Tags: ios, swift, photosframework

If I slide to the left or the right in my gallery, the previous photo remains on the screen for a short moment and then the new one appears.
If I remove the player layer (video) or the image view (photo) the screen gets white (superview background color). How can I fix that? I'm using a fetchResult and fetch the new image to the view.

Here's some code:

```
private func showImage(obj: AnyObject!) {
    var image = UIImage()
    manager.requestImageForAsset(obj as! PHAsset, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .AspectFit, options: photoOptions, resultHandler:
        {(result, info) -> Void in
            image = result!
            self.imageView = UIImageView()
            self.imageView.image = image
            self.imageView.frame = self.contentView.bounds
            self.contentView.addSubview(self.imageView)
    })
}
```

and in the change media, I remove the view/layer:

```
private func changeMedia(index: Int) {
    obj = getObjectAtIndex(index)

    // remove the layer and the view and stop the player if necessary
    imageView?.removeFromSuperview()
    playerLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
    resetPlayer()

    checkMedia(obj)
}
```

> EDIT

```
private func changeMedia(index: Int) {
    obj = getObjectAtIndex(index)

    imageView?.removeFromSuperview()
    playerLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
    resetPlayer()

    checkMedia(obj)
}

private func getObjectAtIndex(index: Int) -> AnyObject {
    let anyObject: AnyObject! = self.allMedia.objectAtIndex(index)

    return anyObject
}
    private func checkMedia(obj: AnyObject) {
    let asset = obj as? PHAsset

    switch asset!.mediaType {
    case .Image:
        showImage(obj)
    case .Video:
        showVideo(obj)
    default:
        print("Unknown media type")
    }
}
```

and changeMedia() is called, if the user slides to the left/right

Comment: what does `manager.requestImageForAsset` do? Does it download the image from the web or locally?

Comment: Locally, from the camera roll

Comment: Everything works but it's not running smooth when there is a Photo->Video->Photo, the first photo remains for just one second altough the 2nd should appear. The 2nd should be displayed immediately

Comment: can you edit your question and show how does it invoke `showImage` method.

Comment: Ok I edited the post

Comment: what are you using for sliding? I think you might need to change your structure for this. i would suggest that you use UIScrollView instead.

Comment: I use UIPageControl. I want to show my images/videos always in fullscreen and so a UIScrollView won't work

Comment: The real problem is that I don't know where I should remove the imageView and the playerLayer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120213/discussion-between-jo3birdtalk-and-mafioso).